# JavaFX: Repaint on desktop unlock

Tags: javafx-2, repaint, unlock

Is there a way to repaint the screen of a JavaFX application when a user returns to the machine and unlocks the computer.

Reason I ask this is that after a user launches the JavaFX application I developed and then locks the desktop and comes back after a few minutes, the JavaFX application screen is blackened out. If the application window is resized, the normal behavior is restored.

I think if the application screen is repainted on desktop unlock that might solve this problem. But the problem at hand is how to capture the desktop unlock event.

Any pointers?

P.S.- I experience this behavior in all javafx applications. Not sure if this is a bug with the current javafx release.

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?  What is your OS/graphic card configuration?  Do you get this issue with the most recent [Java 8 version](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html)?

Comment: Javafx-2.2.0, Graphics card- NVIDIA NVS 5400M. I have not checked with the Java8 version as this is a constraint in the environment for the application. The application needs to work on Java 1.7.

Comment: Is this behavior seen by others also?

Comment: Some causes of this issue were fixed in [Java 8 as part of RT-30362  Some controls become black after screen lock or windowing environment change](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30362).

Comment: Any fixes or workarounds so far without using Java 8?